# How to apply Stolz–Cesàro theorem in this question?

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{2}{2^{2}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \left (\frac{2^{2}}{2^{3}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}} \cdots\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

I don't know how to continue after taking the logarithm of it, after that.
This is an exercise to find the limit using Stolz's method.

Comment: After taking the logarithm, I think it will have the form $\frac{\sum f(i)}{2^n}$. Maybe it will work finding the discrete derivative of the numerator and the denominator and use Stolz's method.

Answer (score 2):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\ln\bigg[\left(\frac{2}{2^{2}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \left (\frac{2^{2}}{2^{3}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}} \cdots\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg] \\
&=&\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{2^{n-k+1}}\ln\bigg(\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^{k}-1}\bigg)\\
&=&\frac{\sum_{k=2}^n2^k\ln\bigg(\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^{k}-1}\bigg)}{2^{n+1}}.
\end{eqnarray}
By Stolz's theorem, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\bigg[\left(\frac{2}{2^{2}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \left (\frac{2^{2}}{2^{3}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}} \cdots\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg] \\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=2}^n2^k\ln\bigg(\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^{k}-1}\bigg)}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}2^k\ln\bigg(\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^{k}-1}\bigg)-\sum_{k=2}^n2^k\ln\bigg(\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^{k}-1}\bigg)}{2^{n+2}-2^{n+1}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n+1}\ln\bigg(\frac{2^{n}}{2^{n+1}-1}\bigg)}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=&\ln(\frac12)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{2}{2^{2}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \left (\frac{2^{2}}{2^{3}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}} \cdots\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac12.$$